# Constraints not satisfied for template template concept requiring static template method

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts, template-templates

I'm trying to implement `Functor` and various other category-theoretic concepts using C++ concepts, but am getting compile errors:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b6eb387229bddf

Here's my full code (I know that requiring `fmap<int, int>` does not verify `fmap` for any two types, and I plan to change it to `fmap<int, std::string>` or something to achieve a slightly stronger test -- or instead, possibly alter the `Functor` concept so that it takes in addition to `F`, two types `T` and `U` and verifies the existence of `fmap<T, U>`, but that's all after I figure out how to fix the error that I'm getting):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// empty Functor_Impl struct - specialize for each functor
template<template<class> class F> struct Functor_Impl {};

// std::vector Functor implementation
template<>
struct Functor_Impl<std::vector> {
    template<class T, class U>
    static std::vector<U> fmap(std::vector<T> x, std::function<U(T)> f) {
        std::vector<U> out;
        out.reserve(x.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            out.push_back(f(x[i]));
        }
        return out;
    }
};

// Functor concept requires Functor_Impl<F> to have fmap
template<template<class> class F>
concept bool Functor = requires(F<int> x) {
    {Functor_Impl<F>::template fmap<int, int>(x)} -> F<int>;
};

// Test function using constraint.
template<template<class> class F, class T>
requires Functor<F>
F<T> mult_by_2(F<T> a) {
    return Functor_Impl<F>::template fmap<T, T>(a, [](T x) {
        return x * 2;
    });
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> x2 = mult_by_2(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x2.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << x2[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the compile error:

```
lol@foldingmachinebox:~/p/website-editor$ g++ foo.cpp -std=c++17 -fconcepts -o foo
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:39:38: error: cannot call function ‘F<T> mult_by_2(F<T>) [with F = std::vector; T = int]’
     std::vector<int> x2 = mult_by_2(x);
                                      ^
foo.cpp:31:6: note:   constraints not satisfied
 F<T> mult_by_2(F<T> a) {
      ^~~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:24:14: note: within ‘template<template<class> class F> concept const bool Functor<F> [with F = std::vector]’
 concept bool Functor = requires(F<int> x) {
              ^~~~~~~
foo.cpp:24:14: note:     with ‘std::vector<int> x’
foo.cpp:24:14: note: the required expression ‘Functor_Impl<F>::fmap<int, int>(x)’ would be ill-formed
```

I'm guessing that my syntax for the concept itself is wrong - that it's treating a variable as a function, or vice versa, since I'm not very familiar with the `concept` syntax, and in addition some of the example code on `cppreference.com` does not compile under GCC's implementation (e.g. `concept EqualityComparable` does not compile, it must be changed to `concept bool EqualityComparable`).

If I remove `requires Functor<F>` from the `mult_by_2` function declaration, then the code compiles and runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message says: `Functor_Impl<F>::template fmap<int, int>(x)` is not a valid expression. `Functor_Impl<std::vector>::fmap` has two parameters, not one.

Comment: lordy, I might just delete this question :/